# Is 'copyfiles' a standard ant task?

Tags: netbeans, ant

I have a NetBeans project that I'm trying to compile manually from command-line `ant`. When running on the same machine that has NetBeans installed, it works flawlessly.

However, if I run `ant` on a central continuous integration server (no NetBeans installed) it fails on a `<copyfiles>` task:

```
BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project_name/nbproject/build-impl.xml:697: Problem: failed to create task or type copyfiles
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

The target is in the auto-generated `build-impl.xml`, which looks something like this:

```
<target depends="init" name="library-inclusion-in-archive" unless="dist.ear.dir">
    <copyfiles files="${file.reference.some_dependency.jar}" todir="${build.web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib"/>
</target>
```

When I look at the [ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/), `copyfiles` isn't even a proper ant task. So what's up?

How can I get this to run on a machine with no NetBeans installation?

Comment: Either grab NetBeans' ant task jar (wherever that is) or duplicate the functionality using standard tasks.

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I was missing. Exact jar is described in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: after i faced the problem again ...  i re installed netbeans that fixed the problem :)

Comment: look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407591/isssue-when-building-the-project-in-netbeans-7-1-2/21138891#21138891

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per [this advice](http://wakka.net/archives/29), I verified the dependencies, and indeed the `lib/CopyLibs` directory was *not* versioned in our source control repo. That's why my local environment was able to compile, but the CI server wasn't.

After adding the dependency to the classpath - `org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar` specifically - the ant build succeeded.

On a personal note, I find it absurd that NetBeans needs an external dependency for a task that - trivially - exists as a standard `ant` task.

Comment: in my case i re installed netbeans that fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

From the Ant Copy man page:

"Important Encoding Note: The reason that binary files when filtered get corrupted is that filtering involves reading in the file using a Reader class. This has an encoding specifying how files are encoded. There are a number of different types of encoding - UTF-8, UTF-16, Cp1252, ISO-8859-1, US-ASCII and (lots) others. On Windows the default character encoding is Cp1252, on Unix it is usually UTF-8. For both of these encoding there are illegal byte sequences (more in UTF-8 than for Cp1252).

How the Reader class deals with these illegal sequences is up to the implementation of the character decoder. The current Sun Java implementation is to map them to legal characters. Previous Sun Java (1.3 and lower) threw a MalformedInputException. IBM Java 1.4 also throws this exception. It is the mapping of the characters that cause the corruption.

On Unix, where the default is normally UTF-8, this is a big problem, as it is easy to edit a file to contain non US Ascii characters from ISO-8859-1, for example the Danish oe character. When this is copied (with filtering) by Ant, the character get converted to a question mark (or some such thing).

There is not much that Ant can do. It cannot figure out which files are binary - a UTF-8 version of Korean will have lots of bytes with the top bit set. It is not informed about illegal character sequences by current Sun Java implementions."

So it looks like NetBeans copyfiles task was created to avoid that unfixable bug when copying Jar files. Not as absurd as it sounds.