# issue when building the project in netbeans 7.1.2?

Tags: java, netbeans, build

I have a project in netbeans 7.1.2 and i get the following problem while i try to build the project

```
D:\netbeans_workspace\Servlets-DWR\nbproject\build-impl.xml:479: The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.
This property must point to 
org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar file which is part
of NetBeans IDE installation and is usually located at 
<netbeans_installation>/java<version>/ant/extra folder.
Either open the project in the IDE and make sure CopyLibs library
exists or setup the property manually. For example like this:
 ant -Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=a/path/to/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can resolve the issue by following these steps:

1. In NetBeans, select Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Ant
2. In the Properties section, add the following property:

**libs.CopyLibs.classpath=/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar**

*Ensure you replace  with the path to the netbeans instance reporting the error. e.g. C:/Program Files/NetBeans 6.9.1*

Comment: Netbeans 7.4 ( Tools > Options > Java > Ant )

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your project is using Ant, but you don't have the Ant plugin installed. To install the plugin, go to `Tools -> Plugins`

Then click the :Available Plugins" tab, click the "Name" header to sort in alphabetical order. Click the check box next to Ant and then click install.

If you don't see "Ant" in the list, you could try clicking "Reload Catalog" in the "Updates" tab.

Answer (score 0):

**A real example is the best solution**

**In  NetBeans 6.9.1**

You can resolve the issue by following these steps:

- In NetBeans, select Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Ant
- In the Properties section, add the following property:

**In  NetBeans 7.4**

- In NetBeans, select Tools > Options > JAVA>
- In the Properties section, add the following property:

In my case the **slashes** and **back slashes** was a real pain so finally ...

> **libs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.1\java\ant\extra\org-netbeans-modules->java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar**

> **libs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans
>    6.9.1\java\ant\extra\org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar**

**EDIT**
**EDIT**
**EDIT**

**After** i faced this problem **again** my solution did **not HELP**
so i read i some page is to reINSTALL netbeans and in my case it worked but note
you dont have only the default property 
`build.compiler.emacs=true`

in your `Tools>Options>Miscellaneous>Ant`  properties part and your project properties is correctly defined like the jdk and server , means look around it then clean and deploy this should work

Ohh look at [some answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386685/is-copyfiles-a-standard-ant-task) it was my comment with shareef user

Answer (score 0):

In any case add the absolute path to org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar not the relative one....

In my case, for DEBIAN and NETBEANS 7.4:

Tools > Options > JAVA

In properties section add:

libs.CopyLibs.classpath=/home/myuser/netbeans-7.4/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar

Y a funcionar.....