# failed to create task or type copyfiles

Tags: xml, ant, build

i am getting following error in build.xml

C:\navigator\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1011: Problem: failed to create task or type copyfiles
Cause: The name is undefined.

build.xml

can anyone suggest me, how to resolve it??

thanks in advance

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532966/the-libs-copylibs-classpath-property-is-not-set-up ?

Answer (score 1):

The copyfiles ant task is not included by default in any apache-ant installation.

Check this : [Is 'copyfiles' a standard ant task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386685/is-copyfiles-a-standard-ant-task)

You should add org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar dependency.